# How do I see a clean git diff despite a merge commit?

Tags: git

Here's the scenario:

Developer A is making changes to his local repository, and then before making those changes available for review, does a pull rather than a fetch and rebase, so he ends up with a giant merge commit containing his changes plus the changes made to the remote repository since he did his last pull.

I want to fetch his changes and see *only what he changed*.

Let's say we're working on a branch called master, and after fetching from his repository, I do this:

git diff master deva/master

I will see a huge confusing diff that does not actually represent the difference between the branches - I see all the files from the merge commit, most of which are not actually different.

So, how do I get a clean diff of just what developer A actually changed, and is there a way for me to clean things up so that when I merge his changes, the merge commit disappears and I have a clean history?

Answer (score 1):

You want `git diff master...deva/master`, which according to the man page for `git diff` is the same as `git diff $(git merge-base master deva/master) deva/master`, or the difference between the point where your branches diverged and the tip of "his" branch.

Of course, the `git diff master deva/master` output is really "what he changed" in some sense, in that it's the difference between your current HEAD and his... It's not lying.

Technically, this can still include things "he didn't change", if they're part of some **other** branch with which "he" merged. If you want to exclude those commits, you're going to have to go through and generate a combined diff.

Comment: But won't that still show me the files from the merge commit, since I'm going all the way back to the common ancestor, which is missing those commits?

Comment: @EricZBeard If you want to skip one commit, you're going to have to go diff-hopping.